# Java HashMap/List alternative for huge data

Tags: java, memory, hashmap

In my Java application i have to scan a filesystem and store recursively the paths of founded files for an early search.

I tried List/ArrayList and HashMap as store structure but the memory usage is TOO much when the filesystem contains 1.000.000+ files.

How can i store and fast retrieve those 'strings' without use an half of my RAM (8 GB)?

Comment: I suggest dumping that data to a file or DB. A plain text file would be good enough

Comment: How often do you scan file system? Can we say that it is constant?

Comment: Yes i already tried DB but i lose 'speed' because i need to search many time for a single entry during the execution. HashMap with containsKey give me a result in O(1) time but DB doesn't.

Comment: No sibnick, this filesystem can change...every scan can be different

Comment: @user3357127 - A hashmap having 1.000.000+ records will almost always have collisions and hence efficiency will not be `O(1)`

Comment: How do you query this storage? something like `boolean isExists(String path)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question can have many answers. People can offer you a wide range of data structure to use or may ask you to increase your hardware memory or heap size of JVM. But I think the problem is somewhere else.

This problem cannot be solved by using just basic datastructures. This may require a change at the design level too. Think about your need. You are asking for such a huge space which is not needed by today's operating system or even RDBMS with very large data in store.

**Data structure as a Service**.(DSAS - it already exist e.g. redis but hey I may have coined this term!).

In your application design, try introducing a component or service like redis, memcached or couchdb which is specialized for doing things like 'storing huge amount of data', 'fast search' over standard sockets or other high speed communication protocol like DBUS.

Do not worry about the internal working of such protocols. There are enough of libraries/apis to do it for you.

Comment: Redis i think could be a great way! I saw there is also the java api for it (jedis) but i can't understand if it create a permanent 'db' or just at runtime every program run...

Comment: redis has got configurations to create permanent db as well. Please look into http://redis.io/topics/persistence for more info.

Answer (score 1):

In the global hashmap instead of storing the full paths as Strings you can store pointers to Dir-Objects.

For each directory you find create a Dir-object. Each Dir-object has a pointer to its parent Dir-object and its local name.

Example:

```
/a/long...path/p/   is a Dir you already found.
/a/long...path/p/a
/a/long...path/p/b  are two new Dirs
```

The two sub Dirs only have to store a reference to the parent Dir plus their local names "a" or "b".

Note that you *do not* have to find the parent Object first: When scanning the file system you should do this recursively or using a Stack explicitly. When you created a Dir-object (e.g. /p here) you then push that object onto a stack and then you visit (go into) that directory. When you are creating the /a and /b sub-Dirs you just look at the top of the stack to find their parent. When you are done with the whole contents of `/a/long...path/p/` then you pop the Dir-object representing it off the stack.

Comment: If i store the object how can i fast search for a path into my hashmap? a loop would be very timeconsuming..

Comment: I think i have to explain better my situation:

I have a SQL DB with paths stored, then i scan filesystem and i have to check for every file i found if this file (the exact path) is already in my DB.

I'm searching a fast and low memory usage way...

Comment: @user3357127 You can store multiple references from your hashmap to a Dir-Object. Example: if you visit `/a/long...path/p/b/x.txt` then you can store a reference to it under the hashmap keys `x.txt` and `b`. You then need a multihashmap or store a vector in each hashmap entry.

Comment: Yes but the problem is that a could find many x.txt files...key will be overriden

Comment: @user3357127 for this scenario you need a multihashmap or store a vector in each hashmap entry. the vector-entries then reference the Dir-objs.

Answer (score 1):

You are storing large number of strings in main memory.It will take memory irrespective of data structure you use.One way might be not to store whole path all the time but to store them in a hierarchical structure eg. storing name of directory in map as a key and storing all values of that directory in list as a value recursively.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to use HashSet and store md5 sum for path:

```
Set<Md5Sum> paths = new HashSet<>();
//for each path
String path = ...
byte[] md5 = messageDigestObject.update(path.getBytes());
path.add(new Md5Sum(md5));
```

You can not use `byte[]` directly as key in hash set. So you need create simple helper class:

```
class Md5Sum{
    //it is more memory effiecient than byte[]
    long part1, part2;
    //override equals and hashCode methods
    //..........
}
```

About updates

You need rescan filesystem and recreate this hash set object, or you can subscribe for file system events (see [WatchService](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/nio/#6)).